# Ho to maintain space between grid in GridLayoutManager when itemview is gone?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-gridlayout

In activity

```
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
```

[image]

inAdapter onBindViewHolder

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.itemView.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        });
```

After itemview gone grid layout not arranged properly

Comment: The screenshot is from your output or the desired output?

Comment: no its current output

Comment: Then, you need to remove the item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the item from your list which you bind in your `GridLayout`.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourlist.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

If you gone particular item then space is always there in view...

**Update**

```
// Gets linearlayout
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.numberPadLayout);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = 0;
params.width = 0;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: by the removing there are new problems are raised which are not maintain here, i already tried it , and its work perfect, but i want to go through GONE method

Comment: "If you gone particular item then space is always there in view.." thats i want to remove

Comment: is any option for itemview width set 0?

Comment: @Vora can you mention the problems that you face when you remove the item?

Comment: that is very length and i removed before few hours, so i changed my stratagy

Comment: visit my previous question  these are my problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452776/how-to-maintain-uploading-task-in-adapter-when-notifyitemremoved-or-notifydatase

Comment: @Vora You have to remove the item from the list. And if you don't want then you have to dynamically set the height of your view as 0.

Comment: "dynamically set the height of your view as 0." and width also 0
but how to do it ?

Comment: Check updated answer : not working space remain constant after set param

Comment: @Vora : the only thing you need to do is you have to remove item from list. That' it.